How do i remove the ActionBar at the bottom of a static date picker in MUI?
<StaticDatePicker
  orientation="landscape"
  openTo="day"
  value={selectedDate}
  onChange={handleDateChange}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
/>

this is my current StaticDatePicker component from MUI, and i want to get rid of the cancel/ok button at the bottom of it, which i assume belongs to the PickersActionBar component.
I have tried to alter the components by adding components={{ PickersActionBar: null }} and other similar methods but to no avail.

As mentioned in mui datepicker docs(https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/static-date-picker/#slots), you can use the slots prop. The component you are trying to remove is called actionBar. You can customize it using slots={{ actionBar: ... }}.

you can override actions via slotProps by passing an empty array there. see below
<StaticDatePicker
  orientation="landscape"
  openTo="day"
  value={selectedDate}
  onChange={handleDateChange}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
  slotProps={{ actionBar: { actions: [] } }}
/>

